Error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace') with ngx-monaco-editor-v2 version 16 and Angular 16
I am facing an issue with monaco-editor, specifically since version 16 of ngx-monaco-editor-v2, monaco-editor v0.41, and angular v16.
The error in console is Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace'), here's a screenshot of the error
error monaco editor
Angular is running in development mode.
nls.ts:53 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'replace')
    at L (nls.ts:53:20)
    at Object.localize (nls.ts:106:10)
    at editorOptions.ts:5680:30
    at s._invokeFactory (loader.js:1203:41)
    at s.complete (loader.js:1213:36)
    at s._onModuleComplete (loader.js:1843:20)
    at s._onModuleComplete (loader.js:1855:30)
    at s._onModuleComplete (loader.js:1855:30)
    at s._resolve (loader.js:1800:22)
    at s.defineModule (loader.js:1443:18)
L @ nls.ts:53
(anonymous) @ nls.ts:106
(anonymous) @ editorOptions.ts:5680
s._invokeFactory @ loader.js:1203
s.complete @ loader.js:1213
s._onModuleComplete @ loader.js:1843
s._onModuleComplete @ loader.js:1855
s._onModuleComplete @ loader.js:1855
s._resolve @ loader.js:1800
s.defineModule @ loader.js:1443
o @ loader.js:1728
b @ nls.ts:192
s._invokeFactory @ loader.js:1203
s.complete @ loader.js:1213
s._onModuleComplete @ loader.js:1843
s._onModuleComplete @ loader.js:1855
s._resolve @ loader.js:1800
s.defineModule @ loader.js:1443
g @ loader.js:1893
(anonymous) @ editor.main.nls.js:11

I tried bumping all to version 17 with angular 17, and still facing the same issue.
I also tried to just declare a basic  in html, just basic config, but same result with error in console, and broken editor.
Here's my package.json:

"dependencies": {
        "@angular/animations": "^16.2.12",
        "@angular/cdk": "^16.2.12",
        "@angular/common": "^16.2.12",
        "@angular/compiler": "^16.2.12",
        "@angular/core": "^16.2.12",
        "@angular/forms": "^16.2.12",
        "@angular/localize": "^16.2.12",
        "@angular/platform-browser": "^16.2.12",
        "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^16.2.12",
        "@angular/router": "^16.2.12",
        "@fortawesome/fontawesome-free": "^6.1.1",
        "@nebular/eva-icons": "12.0.0",
        "@nebular/theme": "12.0.0",
        "@ng-bootstrap/ng-bootstrap": "~15.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/core": "^15.0.0",
        "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^8.0.0",
        "@popperjs/core": "^2.11.8",
        "bootstrap": "5.2.0",
        "chart.js": "^3.9.1",
        "chartjs-adapter-moment": "^1.0.1",
        "d3": "^7.8.0",
        "eva-icons": "^1.1.3",
        "file-saver-es": "^2.0.5",
        "font-awesome-animation": "0.2.1",
        "js-yaml": "^4.1.0",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "monaco-editor": "^0.41.0",
        "ngx-monaco-editor-v2": "^16.0.1",
        "normalize.css": "6.0.0",
        "pace-js": "1.0.2",
        "pako": "^2.1.0",
        "popper.js": "^1.16.1",
        "rxjs": "6.6.7",
        "socket.io-client": "^2.4.0",
        "tslib": "^2.4.0",
        "zone.js": "~0.13.3"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "^16.2.14",
        "@angular-eslint/builder": "16.3.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin": "16.3.1",
        "@angular-eslint/eslint-plugin-template": "16.3.1",
        "@angular-eslint/schematics": "16.3.1",
        "@angular-eslint/template-parser": "16.3.1",
        "typescript": "~4.9.5",
    },

I found 2 issues about the error, but they seem not to be related
https://github.com/microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1192
https://github.com/Microsoft/monaco-editor/issues/1321
Thanks in advance for any help

It looks like you are running the app in prod mode, so the code is minified and the error message is rather cryptic. Try to reproduce the error in dev mode.

If I am not wrong, I am already in development mode.

I'm not sure how did you get such error, but I'm using ngx-monaco-editor-v2@17.0.1 in Angular 17 without any trouble.

Great! Could you provide the dependency config of your project?. Maybe I have a dependency incompatible with ngx-monaco-editor-v2.

@Suppadeliux I think you have a typo please share the config for the monaco editor, if possible a stackblitz with the issue replicated for debugging

UPDATE: I was able to create a stackblitz with the exact versions and it worked, which meant that I had a problem locally.
I was using chrome, and at the end, I only had a cache problem.
The missing option was exactly the option disable cache (while DevTools is open), in preferences settings. (F12 then F1)
